# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: debugging

my website show a fatal error about 'cannot redeclare' [1]. In first moment I though that It was a concrete problem and I deleted some part of code though it was repeated. But the problem is yet, but now with other element.

I have tried updating some modules and the database by Drupal, but I can't.
When database is updating happens an error [2]:

[2] *Fatal error: Class CToolsCssCache contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods.*

[1] *The messege that it's showing is:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare pa3173d21() (previously declared in /var/www/vhost/cdciconianegra.com/home/html/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php:1) in /var/www/vhost/cdciconianegra.com/home/html/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php on line 1*

Could someone help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is D8. What i'm assuming here is that you have duplicate code - how many views directories do you have on your website? First check your installation in terms of setup, i'd look there first.

Answer (score 0):

Since Views is in sites/all/modules, I am guessing this is D7. I would:

- Verify that both [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) are up to
  date.
- Check for copies of modules in `sites/default/modules`
- Run updates again

If it is still complaining about 'redeclare', I would try to flush APC or any server code caching and try [Drush Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild). Then try running updates again.